# How to open Excel if not already open

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to find a way to open Excel using Outlook VBA, but only if it's not already open. I managed to find some code on the internet that opens Excel, does changes and then closes it, but it doesn't behave nicely if the Excel workbook is already open(it does apply the changes, but it no longer closes the Excel workbook, and it simply leaves it with a grey interior; also, sometimes it doesn't even show in the explorer anymore and I have to close it from the task manager).
I would also greatly appreciate if someone could explain what most of the code does.

```
Public xlApp As Object
Public xlWB As Object
Public xlSheet As Object
Sub ExportToExcel()
    Dim enviro As String
    Dim strPath As String
     'Get Excel set up
enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
'the path of the workbook
 strPath = enviro & "\Documents\test2.xlsx"
     On Error Resume Next
     Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
     If Err <> 0 Then
         Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
         Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
         bXStarted = True
     End If
     On Error GoTo 0
     'Open the workbook to input the data
     Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
     Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
    ' Process the message record
    On Error Resume Next
     xlWB.Close 1
     If bXStarted Then
         xlApp.Quit
     End If
End Sub
```

I know what the `xlWb` and `xlSheet` objects do, and how they're declared, and I also understand what the `environ` function and `strPath` string do, but I don't undestand why we need the `bXStarted` boolean, what `Set xlApp = GetObject` does, why the `Application.StatusBar` message doesn't get displayed, the difference between `GetObject` and `CreateObject`and why so many error tests are needed.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between get object and create object is in the title, one will get open `excel.application`, if there is an error `err<>0` then it creates an `excel.application`.  I think you'll be getting a saveas message, as the file may not be saving, but open, and you're instructing it to save, the `error resume next` is skipping it .  Try saving before just a `.close`   If you remove the `on error resume next` the error wont be skipped and will be shown.

```
Sub explaination()

Dim blnDidICreateExcel As Boolean           '   Please read MSDN on boolean
Dim objToHoldExcelCreatedOrNot As Object    '   Please read MSDN on objects create/get

'   Does the user have Excel open, if i try to get it, then there will be an error logically if not
Set objToHoldExcelCreatedOrNot = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

'   Was there an error
If Err <> 0 Then
    '   There was, so i need to create one
    Set objToHoldExcelCreatedOrNot = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    blnDidICreateExcel = True       '   Yes, i created it
End If

'   Do the neccessary

'   CLose the workbook

'   Did i create this Excel, if so tidy up

If blnDidICreateExcel Then objToHoldExcelCreatedOrNot.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: Thing is, the script does save changes. Anyway, are you suggesting I write an `xlWB.Save 1` before the `xlWB.Close 1`?

Comment: take out the on error and see what the error is first.

Comment: The idea from the code, looks like its not meant to close a workbook which is already open, if you do want it to close the users workbook then remove the XStarted check before closing.

Comment: Can't tell what's happening if I remove the last on error, the macro is still behaving like before. Also, I don't really get it, if the code doesn't close a workbook that's already open, how does it open a workbook, make changes to it and then close it?

Comment: It's not the wb closing, `.quit` closes excel.  So it's tidying up whatever it created.

Comment: I'm having a really hard time understanding... So, what does this code do exactly, then?

Comment: If the user has excel open, it grabs the excel object using `getObject` to the variable of the same class type, i.e. `xlApp` although defined as object, it will hold an object of class type `excel.application` if the user doesn't have excel open, it creates it using `CreateObject` and the same with class types.  If it creates excel, it sets the `bXStarted` to true (it's default is false) so it instructs, the `application.quit` to close the Excel it's created, if not it leaves it open.

Comment: Right, now it makes sense. But if that's the case, do you have any idea why Excel gets bugged out when I run the code while it's open?

Comment: I don't know, I cant see your screen.  You'll need to check what's happening in Excel to, as it could be an alert, it could be save has failed, already had the workbook open, could be anything.  If you debug it, stop it at the error, then try err.description to see what the issue is,